# ResolveUrl equivalent to load script without any server technology

Tags: asp.net, html, javascript

I need to take an ASP.NET web page and turn it into a plain HTML web page.

I've done most of the work except for one thing: I couldn't find a way to replace the ASP.NET Page.ResolveUrl function when I set a reference to a javascript file:

```
<script src="<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/MyScript.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I know some users posted questions about a javascript equivalent for the ResolveUrl function but in my case, you have to keep in mind that the solution must be used to load the .js so any reference to a .js library could lead to a Chicken-and-egg problem.

**EDIT**

My web page and my script are included in a framework.  The web page can be deployed in a sub folder and that's the main reason I'm using the ResolveUrl function (and not an hardcoded path).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use relative references depending on the folder were your page is. It's always relative from the page so it will not matter where your website is run from

In the root you can use

```
<script src="Scripts/MyScript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

If your page is in a subfolder, then use

```
<script src="../Scripts/MyScript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

change

```
<script src="<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/MyScript.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

to:

```
<script src="/Scripts/MyScript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

must start with **/** (root folder)

**Update**

Try add: `<base href="http://yoursite.com/mainfolder">`
to head tag.

Comment: This won't work if website is hosted inside a sub-folder. For example, www.mysite.com/marketing/

Comment: ... and it is the case for my web site.

Comment: in this case, try add javascript dynamic, add a baseUrl before all url. I used requirejs(requirejs.org) in my project,
just set:
`requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: 'www.mysite.com/marketing/libs'`

... more at: http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html

Comment: This is the Chicken-and-egg problem I was refering to...  In order to load requirejs, the sub folder path is required.

Comment: I can't tell where my web site will be installed (it could be at 2 different places) so hardcoding web site full url and sub folder isn't an option for me.

Comment: @The_Black_Smurf then you are in a hard spot, you could add a cookie via javascript when you visit the root folder (index.html or some thing like that), then add the base dynamically(with javascript) on all pages.